# How to render component by referring its string type of name?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import ABC from 'asset/image/abc.svg'  //images
import DEF from 'asset/image/def.svg'

const Test = () => {

const myfun = (s)=>{
  return s==='foo'? 'abc':'def'
}

return (
    <div>
        <img src={ /*how_to_use_in_here?*/} /> <span>{s}</span>
    </div>
 )
}

export default Test
```

Is ABC or DEF the React component or element?
How to correctly use component (or element) by referring?

Comment: `ABC` and `DEF` are **.svg**, why are you thinking they could be React component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are importing is the SVG data.

So, you can do:

```
import svgDataA from "svgFileA.svg";
import svgDataB from "svgFileB.svg";

...

const check = 1;
const dataToUse = check ? svgDataA : svgDataB;

...

<img src={dataToUse} style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }} />
```

Comment: I need src of image dynamic change base on my function `myfun`